Can "generation" mean "the amount generated"?
I know "generation" mainly means "the act or process of generating something", but does it also refer to the amount of something generated? For example, do the following sentences mean the same?


The amount of energy generated this year in the US is double that in the UK.
The energy generation this year in the US is double that in the UK.


I thought about this because I'd heard the phrase "the percentage of total energy generation from renewables" somewhere else.

"total energy generation" is a possible way of referring to the cumulative energy generated.

https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=7677bda0a3fd76d6&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ACQVn0_ztqSqeUFktwb8S03AH9COHI_VVA:1714131642448&q=%22total+energy+generation%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMyJX95d-FAxVIl4kEHRKOBFIQ0pQJegQITRAB&biw=1297&bih=684&dpr=1

Some word choices are called "Headlinese" because they are a bit unclear but save space in headlines. So if you need to be concise, consider them, but if you have space, use clearer wording.

No
You're most probably confusing the cause and effect.
In order to create twice the amount, (usually) twice the resources is needed, and more resources to process means twice the process, even if not necessarily twice the "effort"
For example, if a wind turbine were to generate twice the power, then it'll spin twice as fast (we assume of course that this is generating double the power without any optimization effort). The "energy generation" (the cause) is thus increased, in order to increase the "amount of energy generated" (the effect)

By analogy with produce/production generate/generation is not impossible.

silly nitpick, but iirc the power a wind turbine can capture scales as the cube of wind speed (kinetic energy is mv^2, and the air mass per unit time scales with v), and they try to keep their blades moving at a constant ratio to the wind speed, so a turbine going 2x as fast (I believe) is producing 8x the energy.

Because "produce" aside from being a verb, is also a noun. "Generate" is not a noun
